# Editing question that needs to peer reviewed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

Hi All;

I don't have a privilege to edit questions. I edit them and after review that edit it changes. Between the time that I edit the question and editing accepted, that edit is visible only to me. I edit question and title of a question. When I click to question it's OK, I see the edited and only visible for me version. However, when I list the questions (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions) I can't see the title is edited(that title edit should be visible for me)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A change that customizes all the question lists on the site, per-user is totally out of scope.

It would be expensive and incredibly hard to maintain.

Suggested edits are treated as total no-ops by the system *until* they are approved, after they are approved they are **materialized** and the post is edited.

The idea is that if people vandalize the site, the act will be totally hidden - except to the people capable of rejecting it.

Comment: Who approves it? Only originally asking person or any one else can do?

Answer (score 1):

While it is sensible to check for pending edits on a per-question basis, I suspect it makes a bit less sense to have to do that for the entire list each time. And you already *know* that you edited it, right? Most edits are reviewed so quickly that this isn't a significant problem anyway...?

Comment: I tested the problem many times and before getting accepted that edit, this bug happens every time. You are exactly right, most edits are reviewed so quickly however even they are reviewed so quickly, there is a "only visible for you" system. So if it wasn't so important and get reviewed so quickly why to need for only visible for you system? Also I know that it is not a significant problem, but if there is a good system that works, it is good to make it better otherwise not a significant problem, you are right.